# Installing APC on CentOS 5.8 with PHP 5.2.17

Tags: centos5, alternative-php-cache

I'm trying to install APC on CentOS 5.8 with PHP 5.2.17. I ran the dependancies, which weren't needed, and then

`pecl install apc`

and after a whole bunch of stuff, got:

`Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so'
Installing '/usr/local/include/php/ext/apc/apc_serializer.h'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/APC-3.1.9
Extension apc enabled in php.ini`

But, I restarted apache, but APC doesn't show up in phpinfo

[image]

and there was no apc extension added to php.ini

Can I simply add  `extension=apc.so`  to php.ini? And if so, where in the file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same phpinfo page, search for `php.ini` or simple look for "Loaded Configuration File"

Then you can see a path. edit that file and add  your extension.

It can be just anywhere in the file itself. I suggest looking for Extension comments in `php.ini` file and add your extension below them.

Comment: Thanks, this should work fine. But in my case, the problem was that the server was running suPHP, and APC isn't compatible with that. I had to isntall xcache.